# Function cannot be found when creating a new trigger in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a schema in my Postgres, called admin, and on this schema, I've created a new function to do some magic against.

The function needs to be executed from a trigger, however, the creation of this trigger results in a "function cannot be found" exception.

I've confirmed that other functions work as expected, however, this on does not.

I'm no DBA and Postgres is rather new to me so apologies if I'm clearly missing something.

The function creation looks something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION admin.my_magic_func(
   p_schema varchar,
   p_table varchar,
   p_key varchar,
   p_looper _varchar DEFAULT NULL::_varchar)
   /* brevity */
```

This function has been created on the admin schema, and is definitely available, when I query the functions on the 'admin' schema:

[image]

Trying to create the trigger, results in an error stating the function cannot be found:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER test1
    before delete
    ON "admin"."user"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE "admin".my_magic_func('admin', 'user', 'id', null);
```

Which results in an error:

```sql
ERROR: function admin.my_magic_func() does not exist
```

I made sure this is run on the admin schema, and that the function is definitely defined in the admin schema as well.

I believe I have the parameters correct, whereas, the last one, albeit NULL should not be passed unless I really have to.

Is there anything that I'm missing here, or is the error message just really really confusing and not what it actually means?

Appreciate some insight.

Comment: 1) From here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): "Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it expects to receive some arguments specified in CREATE TRIGGER — such arguments are passed via TG_ARGV, as described below." 2) Are you doing `RETURNS trigger`? 3) Not sure why you need arguments as the one's you show should be discoverable in the function.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver you're right, i didn't notice that the function was set up as a non-trigger function, and didn't think of checking that. re-worked the function and all's good. thanks.